# FileMaker obtain a related record with matching parameter

Tags: filter, relationship, record, filemaker

I have two related tables "Objects" and "Measurements"; Objects::ID=Measurements::fk_objectID. For each "object ID" there are multiple "measurements"; measurements have different "date" and  "measurement site". I am trying to display in a layout from "Objects" measurements that fit certain pattern and/or on certain date (for instance on the object release date). I am trying to use ExecuteSQL:

```
ExecuteSQL(
  "SELECT Size
  FROM Measurements 
  JOIN Objects on Measurements.fk_objectID=Objects.ID
  WHERE Measurements.fk_Tissue_ID=2 "
  ; "" ; "")
```

This command returns "Size" values for all Objects IDs, not a single ID which is currently viewed in the layout. It looks like the records are not filtered based on the relationship. making it

```
ExecuteSQL(
  "SELECT Size
  FROM Measurements 
  JOIN Objects on Measurements.fk_objectID=Objects.ID
  WHERE Measurements.fk_Tissue_ID=2 AND Measurements.Date=Objects.ReleaseDate"
  ; "" ; "")
```

returns mistake.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer ExecuteSQL() over Filmaker's native methods - for example portal filtering? Note that ExecuteSQL() is a completely independent ecosystem: it ignores Filemaker's relationships and the current context (found set, current record, etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use portal since I need the value to be in a defined field which is further used for other downstream calculations. I do not mind using native FM filtering, just do not know how

Comment: There are other tools you can use. Please edit your question and explain the requirement in more (specific) detail.